Is there a way to execute a block of code after Click() is simulated in javascript?
What am I trying to do?

There is an e-commerce site that obfuscates/hides the buyer information (on seller side of the platform) until you click on the switch to toggle a SWITCH-ON state.
I am simulating a click() on a switch with javascript to display hidden information
information (I assume) is pulled from a backend server
I need to store the information after the contents are displayed through the switch-on toggle

What have I done?

Simulated a click event on the switch with

document.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-children")[0].click();


Information is displayed as if I were to toggle the switch manually. It's a success.
I can see the values, but I face a problem when trying to store it.
The stored values are hidden values from before the click() event is simulated. (I want to store values that the server gives back after the click event has happened)
So, when I am expecting to get the value Shamona(example), I am instead getting S*a stored in receiver.


My code:
// I have this click event

    document.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-children")[0].click();

// And I can't figure out how to execute the following block of code 
// after click is simulated and data is pulled from backend.

    const receiverField = document.getElementsByClassName("order-field-shipping-receiver-name")[0];
    const receiverName = receiverField.getElementsByClassName("order-field-value")[0];
    receiver = receiverName.getElementsByClassName("show-text")[0].textContent;
    console.log(receiver)


How it looks:

The value is hidden like this at SWITCH-OFF

The value is displayed when the switch is toggled to SWITCH-ON

The console.log(receiver) outputs

S*a


I am getting S*a instead of Shamona(example) because the code below gets executed right after the click() event happens but before the hidden values can be populated with the ones from the server.


How do I remedy this?

Tried the following:
Eventlistener to DOMContentLoaded
callback that fires when the first function is completed to start the second function.
foo bar method

If I could listen to an attribute change event like div class= next-switch-off turning to next-switch-on , would that work?
What would be the best way to solve this. Open to any suggestions.

Please [edit] your question to include the relevant html and show how you attempted to implement the "tried the following" items.

@mykaf I tried it on a chrome extension I am building to do this. Unfortunately, the switch will not even work when I include the relevant html in a fiddle. It only works with the chrome extension because the switch functions are already there on the e-commerce's live webpage. I am just trying to find out if anyone has done anything similar.

You cannot use DOMContentLoaded since that triggered way before you can trigger the click. You can however use a mutationobserver

Check the docs for mutation observer

document.getElementsByClassName("next-switch-children")[0].click(); should be: document.querySelector(".next-switch-children").click();. Avoid using getElementsByClassName

@ScottMarcus While the general advice is good, I don't think there's any case where those two expressions would be different.

You'll probably be better off using something that emulates a user, like Selenium WebDriver or Puppeteer, than doing this in JavaScript.

@Barmar I want this to function as a Chrome extension so I have to follow this route right now. But I will keep your advice in mind for future purposes.

@James I got limited success with Mutation (perhaps because it is a new concept for me). The click() simulation triggered the mutation observer 6 times, because 3 attributes were modified. Most of the time, I get the desired Shamona , but once in a while S*a also pops out. So I am not being able to do it reliably.

The basic issue is that you may need to reverse-engineer the e-commerce code. It can react to the click in a number of different ways (e.g. listeners for "mousedown" and "mouseup" instead of just "click"). It's also possible for paranoid code to distinguish real clicks from simulated clicks.

If they don't want you automating their site, they can make it pretty hard.

@Barmar the click() has worked as expected and populated desired fields with data. When I go to retrieve that data, my code runs before the fields are populated, so I get obfuscated information. I hope I am clear with this. I an new to Mutation Observer, so I may be having problems. I will give it a few days., while peeling ears for more suggestions.

@Barmar Using live node lists can hurt performance. I have personally seen the dramatic difference, especially when looping over a live node list.

@ScottMarcus The nodelist is going the be GC'ed immediately, I doubt there's much performance impact.

@Barmar I've seen dramatic delays when looping over a live node list and accessing the list within the loop as compared to using a static node list.

@ScottMarcus I understand that. But he's NOT looping over anything. He's just accessing the first element, a one-time operation. The node list is temporary and goes away immediately, it's not saved in a variable.

The problem, I think, is that your click() starts an asynchronous task... But your next lines are executed before the asynchronous task could complete. That's why the data is obfuscated... Maybe you should wrap them in an event closure and bind it to the same click event listener... Like document.querySelector(".next-switch-children").getEventListener('click').then(...).

After trying out some great suggestions from the comments:

Mutation Observer - I wasn't able to make this work consistently. I put up an observer for attribute changes and it would record the correct data 50% of the time, but it would frequently record the hidden data because the correct data simply wasn't populated in time even with the attribute change.
Event Closure - I wasn't able to use this because it would not allow then()


So what I did:

I looped over the receiverName until * was no longer present
I used async await to do this. I basically wanted a block of code to stall before moving on with the proper data and it works really consistently.

//async loop to poll the element until * is absent
while (document.querySelector(".order-field-shipping-receiver-name .order-field-value .show-text").textContent.includes("*")) {
await asleep(100);
}
const receiverName = document.querySelector(".order-field-shipping-receiver-name .order-field-value .show-text").textContent

ps. I did change my code to use querySelector instead of getElementsByClassName whenever possible
